# Is there a way to sort month and year string in google sheet or presto sql?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, presto

I have data that looks like this:

```
campaign_type
marmay2022
janmar2022
mayjul2022
```

I'm trying to sort it based on the year and the first 3 character according to the month and year.

Comment: So what are you using? Google sheets or presto?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX(SORT({A2:A4,--("01/"&REPLACE(A2:A4,4,3,"/"))},2,1),0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=QUERY({A1:A3,ArrayFormula(DATEVALUE("01-"&LEFT(A1:A3,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1:A3,4)))},"select Col1 order by Col2")
```

[image]